# Do I need to edit SCT Error Recovery Control time?

Tags: hard-drive, toshiba-hard-drive

I plan to setup raid6 (lsi) or make pool(windows10). I have several hdds.

```
=== START OF INFORMATION SECTION ===
Model Family:     Toshiba MG07ACA... Enterprise Capacity HDD
Device Model:     TOSHIBA MG07ACA12TE
Serial Number:    
LU WWN Device Id: 5 000039 968caa99a
Firmware Version: 0101
User Capacity:    12 000 138 625 024 bytes [12,0 TB]
Sector Sizes:     512 bytes logical, 4096 bytes physical
Rotation Rate:    7200 rpm
SMART support is: Available - device has SMART capability.
SMART support is: Enabled

SCT capabilities:              (0x003d) SCT Status supported.
                                        SCT Error Recovery Control supported.
                                        SCT Feature Control supported.
                                        SCT Data Table supported.
```

I have such settings

```
C:\Windows\system32>smartctl -l scterc /dev/sda

SCT Error Recovery Control:
           Read: Disabled
          Write: Disabled
```

Do I need to setup timeout?

`smartctl -l scterc,70,70 /dev/sda`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, if you use RAID of any sort (traditional or ZFS), you should enable it to avoid long stalls when a bad sector is encountered. If you have redundancy, it is better to accept an error and reconstruct the block from parity than to block on I/O for minutes.

Arguably you should enable it even without RAID. A sector read can be attempted 120 times per second on a 7200 rpm disk. That is 840 times in 7 seconds. If 840 attempts to read the sector failed, the probability that it will ever succeed is sufficiently close to 0 that you might as well not waste any more time on it.

Comment: Thanks a lot! You mean that 7sec is correct value for raid?

Comment: Yes, 7s is the default value commonly used everywhere where SCT ERC is enabled. I don't know why 7s was chosen, but many disks only support a setting of 7s or off, with no other options.